# "No symbol version section for versioned symbol"

Tags: c, linux, gcc, curl, cross-compiling

I'm attempting to cross-compile my own shared library (libmystuff.so) against another shared library (libtheirstuff.so) that makes use of the libcurl shared library and am getting the following error:

```
libmystuff.so: No symbol version section for versioned symbol 
'curl_global_init@@CURL_OPENSSL_3'
```

Which is then followed by:

```
final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output.
```

Going through the code that creates libtheirstuff, I can see that curl_global_init is the first reference to curl.

Doing `ldd libtheirstuff.so` on the target platform (arm5) shows that it can find all of the references.

What's going on here?

Edit: Here are the calls to gcc

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -fPIC -c mystuff_impl.c -o mystuff_impl.o -I/home/me/arm/include
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -shared -Wl,soname=libmystuff.so -o libmystuff.so.0.1 mystuff_impl.o -L/home/me/arm/lib -ltheirstuff
```

Comment: Could it be the order in which you are linking the libs?

Comment: I'm only linking the one library. See edit for the calls to gcc.

Comment: Looks like other people have had similar problems.  Perhaps another version of the curl lib needs to be used, one that is compatible with that theirstuff lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linker was grabbing the wrong version.

Answer (score 0):

This problem (`No symbol version section for versioned symbol 
'curl_global_init@@CURL_OPENSSL_3'`) also appears when you are trying to compile a binary that will work on multiple Linux distributions. You can check for the problem like this:

```
$ objdump -x mybinary | grep curl_global_init
0... F *UND*  0... curl_global_init@@CURL_OPENSSL_3
```

The solution in this case is to build on a machine where libcurl has been compiled with `./configure --disable-versioned-symbols`. Binaries compiled this way will work elsewhere (including on systems which use versioned symbols). A portable binary should produce output like this (without any `@` signs):

```
$ objdump -x mybinary | grep curl_global_init
0... F *UND*  0... curl_global_init
```